# Android global variables in class extending application or not?

Tags: java, android

I want to create some global variables in my android application, for example when the user logs in i want to have a variable to hold the username.

Should i create a `MyApplication extends Application` and add the variables in there or should i just create a "MyGlobals" class with public static variables inside?

Which one is better and why?

Comment: If you extend your application class, you can override some of its methods, on top of plain static variables. Please dont forget to edit your manifest. This is what I am using, but I had some problems with changing code during execution functionality.

Comment: The best global variable is _no global variable_. The username of a logged user should be held in the entity that can provide the rest of the app information about the logged user. "Kids" call it "presenters" these days, but you can manage that as you please. Dagger (or Dependency Injection) is nice, but adds complexity (a lot) makes things "magical" and the fact that makes "testing" easier is overrated. Yes, it's nice, but the amount of code dagger generates… and the ramp-up complexity may not be worth if the project is small and you have no Dagger experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases a class is extended, although other solutions exist.
Extend the base android.app.Application class and add member variables:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private String yourVar;

    public String getYourVar() {
        return yourVar;
    }

    public void setYourVar(String yourVar) {
        this.yourVar = yourVar;
    }
}
```